# Difference between constant of motion and conserved quantity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, scattering, interactions

For a scattering process let $S$ the scattering operator and $P_0$ the energy operator of the system. We define R to be a constant of motion if

$[R,P_0] = 0$

and we define C to be a conserved quantity if

$[C,S] = 0$.

It is easy to see that there are constants of motion that are not conserved and the other way around, so those are non equivalent. I can see that the definition of 'constant of motion' fits the quantum mechanical picture where $P_0$ is the Hamiltonian and the motion is given by the Schroedinger equation. And clearly conserved quantity simply means that it does not change during the scattering process.

But I cannot quite understand what the difference between those two is especially concerning the physical interpretation. For me they both say that a quantity does not change as the systems evolves. Can someone point out exactly in which way they differ?

(The definitions are taken from the book "An Introduction to Symmetry and Supersymmetry in Quantum Field Theory" from Jan Lopuszánski)

Comment: "It is easy to see that there are constants of motion that are not conserved and the other way around, so those are non equivalent." --> Can you give an example? Normally I would define the S-matrix in terms of the energy operator as $S_{\alpha \beta}=\langle  \alpha | Te^{i \int dt P_0} | \beta \rangle$, where $P_0$ is the energy operator, $T$ is time ordering, and $\alpha,\beta$ label in and out states. (See, eg, Section 3.1 of Tong's lecture notes, http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/three.pdf). Then I have a hard time seeing how you could commute with $S$ and not $P_0$ or vice versa.

Comment: The generators of the Lorentz boost are not conserved quantities but constants of motion, and the asymptotic particle number operator is a constant of motion but no conserved quantity. Lopuszánski defined the scattering operator abstractly by saying that the in- and out-Hilbert spaces have a common vacuum which is cyclic for both, and thus we must have a unitary operator ("base change") connecting those two Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Actually I'm surprised that generators of Lorentz boost are considered constants of motion. The energy does transform under a Lorentz boost, and in the Poincaire algebra, one finds the commutator $[M_{\mu \nu},P_\rho]=\eta_{\ \mu\rho} P_\nu - \eta_{\nu \rho}P_\mu$ (where $P_\mu$ is the generator of translation and $M_{\mu\nu}$ the generator of boosts and rotations). If I take, for instance, $\mu=0, \rho=0,\sigma=1$, then I get that $[M_{01},P_0] = P_1 \eta_{00}=-P_1$, which is not zero.

Comment: Oh you are right, I got it the wrong way around! Surely we have $[M_{\mu,\nu}, S] = 0$, but as you said they do not commute with the Poincare algebra.

Comment: Ah ok that makes more sense. I am still not 100% convinced that $[M_{\mu\nu},S]=0$, I would think that the the S-matrix should transform under a Lorentz transformation, but not remain invariant.

Comment: We find for $U(a,A)$ the representation of the Poincare group, $S^ {-1}U(a,A)\phi_{A\dot{B}}^in(x)U(a,A)^{-1}S = (A^{-1})_A^C\bar{(A^{-1})}_{\dot{B}}^{\dot{D}} \phi^{out}_{C\dot{D}}(\Lambda x + a) = U(a,A) \phi^{out}_{A\dot{B}}(x) U(a,A)^{-1} = U(a,A)S^{-1}\varphi^{in}_{A\dot{B}}(x) S U(a,A)^{-1}$ and the set of incoming fields is supposed to be irreducible, thus $[S,U(a,A)] = 0$ follows.

Comment: I think maybe the subtlety is that one can define an S-matrix operator, $\hat{S}=T e^{i \int_{-\infty}^\infty dt P_0}$, which will transform under Lorentz boosts. But the S-matrix itself sandwiches this operator between states. So an individual scattering amplitude (S-matrix element) is Lorentz invariant, even though the time evolution operator will transform under boosts. I need to think more to see if I can formalize this intuition. But I suspect this is a key point for your question. Maybe there is someone else on the site that knows more though :)

Comment: @S.Farr, by conserved quantity do you mean something that is Lorentz invariant or something that is invariant under some wider group of transformations, e.g. the Poincare group?

Comment: @Physics_ET_Al, as stated, a conserved quantity is simply some operator that commutes with the scattering operator of the system. There is no direct connection to the transformation under a space symmetry group.

Comment: @S.Farr, okay. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but is it possible to write down a power series for the scattering operator? This would involve powers of integrals of $P_0$ so one obtains of terms involving $ \propto [C,T(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P_0 dt)^n]$.

Comment: I do not have any explicit form of the scattering operator, I am working in the context of the Wightman axioms, and the only information on the scattering operator is that it should transform the chosen orthonormal basis of the incoming Hilbert space into this of the outgoing Hilbert space while leaving the vacuum invariant.

Comment: I can't help further. Sorry.

Comment: @mike stone, have you seen this question?